# Pandas date time format

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Currently, I am working in 2.2 Million records. Where two column consist of `membership_id` and `txn_time`. The data frame looks like -

```
membership_id          txn_time
 1                      2019-02-17 00:00:00.0
 2                      2018-04-23 00:00:00.0
 3                      2018-12-17 00:00:00.0
 4                      2019-02-17 00:00:00.0
 5                      2018-04-02 00:00:00.0
 6                      2018-09-10 06:20:58.0
 7                      2019-01-16 08:11:42.0
```

I want the data frame looks like -

```
membership_id          txn_time
 1                      2019-02-17 
 2                      2018-04-23 
 3                      2018-12-17 
 4                      2019-02-17 
 5                      2018-04-02 
 6                      2018-09-10
 7                      2019-01-16
```

What I have done so far -

```
df_txn['TXN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_txn['txn_time'], errors='coerce')
```

But, it's not working and the no of records is huge 2.2 million.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But it's not working and the no of records` there is error? Or slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For improve performance use parameter `format`, then convert to datetimes with no `time`s by [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), better if need process data later by datetimelike function(s):

```
df_txn['TXN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_txn['txn_time'], 
                                    errors='coerce',
                                    format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('d')
```

Or to `python date`s by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), but get `object`:

```
df_txn['TXN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_txn['txn_time'], 
                                    errors='coerce',
                                    format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

This lambda function would help you solve the problem without using datetime library.

```
df['txn_time'] = df['txn_time'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
```